# It's possible to connect static html subpages with wordpress page?

Tags: html, wordpress, static, content-management-system

For example. I have already designed above pages and i don't want to use wordpress for About and Contact page and use it only for blog to manage content:
About (html)
Blog (wordpress)
Contact (html)
It is possible to connect it like that? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serve your site normally and install WordPress in a sub directory. See the official documentation on [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can Do that,

First Create Custom Page Template

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: About
    */
    ?>
   ------Your HTML here------
```

Next Create a page in Wordpress admin and assign the custom template
[Set Custom template Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLq75.jpg)

Like this, you can create multiple templates for multiple pages

note: Make Sure all Template Files in PHP.